# How to make a void pointer to read a given part of a binary file

Tags: c, struct, io, binaryfiles

I have a binary file which contains 3 differents structs and a christmas text. On the first line of the binaryfile have they provided me with a int which represents the size of a package inside the file. A package contains 3 structs ,the chistmastext and the size.
The structs lies in a file called framehdr.h and the binary file I'm reading is called TCPdump.

Now am I trying to create a program att will read each package at a time and then withdraw the text. 
I have started with something like this:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "framehdr.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
  FILE *fileOpen;
  char *buffer;
  size_t dataInFile;
  long filesize;

  // The three structs
  struct ethernet_hdr ethHdr;
  struct ip_hdr ipHdr;
  struct tcp_hdr tcpHDr;

  fileOpen = fopen("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\source\\repos\\Laboration_3\\Laboration_3\\TCPdump", "rb");
  if (fileOpen == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Success\n");
  }

  char lenOf[10];
  size_t nr;
  // Reads until \n comes 
  fgets(lenOf, sizeof(lenOf), fileOpen);
  sscanf(lenOf, "%d", &nr);
  // Withdraw the size of a package and check if it's correct
  printf("Value: %d\n", nr);
  printf("Adress: %d\n", &nr);

  void *ptr;
  fread(&ptr, nr, 1, fileOpen);
  int resEth = 14;
  printf("resEth: %d\n", resEth);
  int resIP = IP_HL((struct ip_hdr*)ptr);
  printf("ResIP: %d\n", resIP);
  int resTcp = TH_OFF((struct tcp_hdr*)ptr);
  printf("tcpIP: %d\n", resTcp);
  int res = resEth + resIP + resTcp;
  printf("Total: %d", res);

  fclose(fileOpen);
  //free(buffer);

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

I know that the first struct ethernet will always have the size of 14 but I need to get the size of the other 2 and I'm suppose to use IP_HL and TH_OFF for that.

But my problems lies in that I can't seem to read the entire package to one
void * with the fread. I get noting in my *ptr.
Which in turn makes the code break when I try to convert the void * to one of the structs ones.

What I'm doing wrong with the void *?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it's indenten at my end. Must mad an error when I put it in here. Will fix it

Comment: `ptr` doesn't point to anything... Allocate some memory first.

Comment: You have a *binary* file, from which you are reading a line (or at least part of one) via the *text*-oriented `fgets()` function.  That could be ok, depending on the format of the file, but it's certainly suspicious.

Comment: @JohnBollinger what should I use instead of fgets()?

Comment: @anderssinho, `fread()` or maybe `fgetc()`.  And if the number you are trying to read is expressed in binary form inside the file then you'll need to know what that form is and how to convert that to an appropriate in-memory form (which may or may not be trivial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

First you should not really use text functions when reading binary files. Binary files doesn't really have "lines" in the sense that text file have it.

Secondly, with

```
void *ptr;
fread(&ptr, nr, 1, fileOpen);
```

you are passing a pointer *to the pointer variable*, you don't actually read anything into memory and then make `ptr` point to that memory. What happens now is that the `fread` function will read `nr` bytes from the file, and then write it to the memory pointed to by `&ptr`, which will lead to *undefined behavior* if `nr > sizeof ptr` (as then the data will be written out of bounds).

You have to allocate `nr` bytes of memory, and then pass a pointer to the first element of that:

```
char data[nr];
fread(data, nr, 1, fileOpen);
```

---

You should also get into the habit of *checking for errors*. What if the `fread` function fails? Or the file is truncated and there isn't `nr` bytes left to read?

You can check for these conditions by checking what [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) *returns*.

And not only check for `fread`, there are more functions than `fopen` that can fail.